# Consulta SqlDataAdapter com Parâmetros

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, ado.net

Estou tendo dificuldades no retorno de uma consulta no banco de dados utilizando `SqlDataAdapter` com parâmetros.

Bem, eu tenho uma aplicação em camadas, na minha View quando acesso pela primeira vez alimento uma `GridView` com uma consulta (esta parte tá ok)!

Nesta mesma View tem um campo para pesquisar e filtrar nesta mesma `GridView`, atualizando-a com esta filtragem, e que usa o mesmo método. Aí que dá o erro, utilizei alguns exemplos que achei na net mas não tá dando certo.

Quando entra na linha dentro o `if` que tem o código a seguir, entra no `catch`:

```
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nome", pessoa.Nome));
```

O erro informado no `catch` é o seguinte:

```
{System.NullReferenceException: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.}
```

Como eu poderia adicionar este parâmetro da forma correta?

Segue o código:

```
public DataTable listarPessoas(PessoaModel pessoa = null)
{
    try
    {
        conectar();

        queryString = "SELECT * FROM [crud].[dbo].[Pessoas]";

        if (pessoa.Nome != null)
            queryString += " WHERE pess_nome LIKE '%@nome%'";

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        if (pessoa.Nome != null)
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nome", pessoa.Nome));

        conn.Open();
        adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception erro)
    {
        throw erro;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, acabei recebendo ajuda de um amigo e ele me ajudou com o código, no fim não usei SqlDataAdapter, ficando assim o código:

```
public DataTable listarPessoas(PessoaModel pessoaModel)
{
    string queryString = "SELECT * FROM [Crud].[dbo].[Pessoas]";

    if (pessoaModel != null)
        if (pessoaModel.Id != 0)
            queryString += " WHERE pess_id = @id";
        else if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pessoaModel.Nome))
             queryString += " WHERE pess_nome LIKE @nome";

    try
    {
        conectar();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);

        if (pessoaModel != null)
            if (pessoaModel.Id != 0)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", pessoaModel.Id);
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pessoaModel.Nome))
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", '%' + pessoaModel.Nome + '%');

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Load(reader);
        reader.Close(); // Fecha o DataReader

        return dt;
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        return null; // em caso de Exceções retorna null 
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close(); // Fecha a conexão com o banco de dados
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você tenha que por essa linha antes do `if`:

```
    adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
```

Pois `adapter.SelectCommand`, ainda deve ser `null` quando você o tenta acessa-lo.

Ficaria algo assim:

```
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd; // essa linha antes, para não deixa a instancia nula

    if (pessoa.Nome != null)
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nome", pessoa.Nome));

    conn.Open();
```

Faz tempo que não uso `SqlCommand`, mas acredito que seja só isso.

Comment: Vlw @Fernando, nem vi sua resposta. Acabei conseguindo resolver, mas darei um +1.